# Are there any good resources on keyboard event handling in Windows Runtime?

Tags: keyboard, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I need to to process keyboard events in TextBox controls (and other UI elements) in Windows RT, but have some problems. For example, the KeyDown event handler seems not to be fired in the TextBox when the backspace key is pressed (*CoreWindow::KeyDown fires, though, but that has other problems described below*).

I've been trying to find good resources on how keyboard event handling is dealt with in Windows RT, but haven't found any but lightweight documentation on the topic (eg. which classes exists etc). Any pointers to samples and other resources on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

In particular, I'd like to learn how keyboard events are processed in general in Windows RT, to answer questions such as "*Why does my TextBox::KeyDown event fire **before** my CoreWindow::KeyDown event?*".

Answer (score 1):

Though I haven't found any resources on the topic, I have found a solution to some of the problems I had. I'm posting it here for future reference hoping that it'll help others.

*How to capture backspace, arrow-keys and other keypresses in a TextBox*

Subclass the textbox and override OnKeyDown(). If you don't call the superclass implementation, the KeyDown event will now be fired on most (if not all) keypresses, but you probably don't want to bypass all the internal keyboard handling of the TextBox, so beware. Best is to put your logic in the override and call the superclass implementation.